# Text field not updating in a web page after entering the value using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page which takes data from key board and saves data in the server using a function.Everything is well if datas are given from keyboard or through copy/paste method.But When I used a bookmarklet to change its value it changes the value on the page but not updating it to the server.Server shows the datas which are only entered through key board or copy/paste method.here is the html code

`<input type="Text" style="width: 373px" name="ProductName" id="ProductName" maxlength="1000" onchange="saveFieldData(4734, this, 'docProductInfo', 'ProductName', 4734);" value="Satyaranjan" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">`

I want to change the value of `"id=ProductName"` using `value`,but it does not update the value to server.here is my bookmarklet code

`javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('ProductName').value="";})();`

It works well when data taken from keyboard but when I enter the data using `value` it does not update the data to server.I think if I could access the function `saveFieldData()`  using bookmarklet then it could update the data to server.So please help me and tell me is there any way to update the data to server using bookmarklet.I am using Chrome browser.

Comment: first make sure the function runs by putting a console.log or alert in the function. second, make sure that the element is found with that id. the code should work, there is nothing wrong with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most-likely need to manually call `saveFieldData()` method:

```
javascript:(function(){var name=document.getElementById('ProductName');name.value="";saveFieldData(4734,name,'docProductInfo','ProductName',4734);})();
```